# Hide Div on Window Maximize & Resize > 1600px - JQuery

Tags: jquery

How would I hide a HTML div when the browser window is either maximized or resized greater then 1600px using jquery?

I currently have it set so the div hides when the page is greater then 1600px on load but cannot get it to hide when the window is maximized or resized after the page has loaded. Below is the code I have used:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
      $('#next').hide();
  $('#back').hide();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){

if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
      $('#next').fadeOut();
} else {
  $('#next').fadeIn();
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){

 if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
       $('#next').hide();
   $('#back').hide();
  }

});



$('.work').click(function(){ 
   if ($(window).width() < 1600){
     $('#next').fadeIn('slow'); 
   }
});
```

Comment: That worked great! but I now have another problem. I have an anchor that is set to show that div when clicked but I do not want it to show when the anchor is clicked with the window > 1600px. The code I have used on the anchor is                $('.work').click(function(){
$('#next').fadeIn('slow');
});

Comment: The problem I am now running into is the div I have set to hide when the window is > 1600px and show if else is showing up on sections I do not want it to show up on when the window is resized > 1600px then sized down < 1600px. Is there way to have the div not show at a certain x position even if the window is resized? Here is a link to the site I am working on http://tamedia.ca/normli/. It is the bright green arrow pointing to the right (mid screen/right side) that I am having issues with. Thanks

Comment: Use window.screenX to get the x-position of the window.

Comment: I am a little green and would really appreciate if you could please explain in detail. Basically I do not want the div that I have set to show when the window is sized down < 1600px to show at any x position past 1600px.

Comment: I am not clear about your requirement. Can you create a new question based on this or explain it in detail?

Comment: I have used your suggested code (see my edited code above) and have added 'else show div'. So the div hides when the screen is > 1600px and shows when the screen is < 1600px. The only problem with this is my page is 10000 px wide and I only want the div to show with-in the first 1600 px of the page no matter what the window size. Here is a link to the site I am working on http://tamedia.ca/normli. It is the bright green arrow pointing to the right (mid screen/right side) that I am having issues with. Thanks and I apologize if I am not providing you with the right info I am very green.

Comment: Then checking the window widht an height is enough to control the div visibility.

Comment: The problem I am having is the site is a horizontal scrolling site with 5 different sections on one page. I have overflow set to hidden and when you click on a link in top nav it scrolls to that section, each section is about 2000 px apart. I only want the div to show on the first section which is with-in the first 1600 px of the page. When you are on a section other then the first one the div will show if the page is initially > 1600px then sized down < 1600px. Is there a way so no matter the screen size when the window position is past the first 1600px that div will never show? Thanks

Comment: I appreciate all of your help very much and will post another question. Thanks and have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it has worked perfect for me:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

if ($(window).width() < 700) {
 $(".div").hide();
};

$(window).on("resize", function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 700) {
  $(".div").hide();
 }
 else {
  $(".div").show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute some code if the browser window is maximized, you can probably use this:

```
var a = screen.width;
var b = $(window).width();
var c = b + 17; // add the width of the scrollbar
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) {
  var d = c + 4; // add width of border on Windows
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {
  var d = c + 2; // add width of border on Mac
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) {
  var d = c + 6; // add width of border on Linux
}

if (a == d) {
// code to run if width of browser window matches width of user's screen
} else {
// code to run otherwise
}
```

And you might want to use a callback function to make the code run even after the divs have been hidden once.

**EDIT:** I added the width of the scrollbar to the `$(window).width()` variable, and I put in an OS identification system, to add the OS's specific browser border to the variable. You could do this for the scrollbar as well, if necessary.

Source for OS Identifier: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm

Comment: `$(window).width()` does not include the width of any vertical scrollbar. And on many OS's windows also have a border that needs to be taken into account.